# Remove Key of One Array of Not Have in Other Array

Tags: php, arrays, key, unset

I Have to Remove The Key of One Array
Of Not Have in Another Array, Like

```
    /**
     * I Have This Array, With Keys
     * Name, Lastname, Date
     */
    $Array = Array( 'name' => 'Mike', 'lastname' => 'Griggs', 'date' => strftime( '%A %c' ) );
    /**
     * And The Split , Make This One Array
     */
    $Fields = 'name, lastname';
    foreach( split( ',', str_replace( ' ', NULL, $Fields ) ) as $Index => $Field ):
             if(!array_key_exists( $Field, split( ',', str_replace( ' ', NULL, $Fields )))):
                   unset( $Array[$Field] );
             endif;
    endforeach;
    print_r( $Array );
    /**
     * i Have to Remove The Elements of $Array
     * That Not Have in $Fields, In This Case, Unset 'date' From $array
     */
```

But Retorning The Date Field in Array
I Need to Unset The Keys Of Not Have in $Fields From Array, 
If Dont Have Name in Array, Return Only LastName ..

Thanks []'s

Comment: Why Are You Capitalizing Every Single Word?

Comment: Sorry, Dont Understand You Question =)

Comment: i Trying to Remove The Keys From $Array of Not Have in  $Fields

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should consider formating your questions in proper English. Mostly because users will either criticize it instead of answering it or ignore it completely.

That being said, I assume you have an array and a string with comma separated indexes. Then you want to "sanitize" your array by removing extra data.

Here's an example on how you might do that:

```
<?php
$array = Array( 'name' => 'Mike', 'lastname' => 'Griggs', 'date' => strftime( '%A %c' ) );
$fields = 'name, lastname';

function removeIndex($a,$f){
    $f=explode(',',$f);
    $b=array();
    foreach($f as $v){
        $v=trim($v);// only need if you have extra whitespace
        $b[$v]=$a[$v];
    }
    return $b;
}

$array=removeIndex($array,$fields);
print_r($array);
?>
```

Comment: Stop capitalizing every word. I'm glad it works.

Comment: how i can 'unset' the field ?

Comment: Which field from where? You just said it works.

Comment: Ye, But Don't Unseting The Field From Array :p

Comment: .............. I don't understand what you want. You don't need to unset anything. Stop capitalizing every word.

Comment: Ok, I want to remove the key from $array that's not the same keys exist in $field

Comment: What doesn't work with my example ?

Comment: i need to unset man =), remove from array, because i have to implode some things after

Comment: Did you test the function? Do you understand what it does?

Comment: Yep, i know , but i have to unset the key or keys from array

Comment: Why do you need to do that? You can just rewrite the array with the function supplied above.